# htaccess redirect subfolder of certain domain

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, subdomain, subdirectory, drupal-domain-access

I have a multi-subdomain multi-lingual website setup and I need to redirect a language subfolder of a certain domain. eg. au.domain.com/us/request_uri to au.domain.com/en/request_uri. This rule needs to be ignored on other domains. All domains are run off the same codebase and all use the one htaccess file (drupal install with domain access module). This shouldn't affect how the htaccess rule is set though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^us/(.*)$ http://au.domain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Redirects:

`http://au.domain.com/us/anything` to

`http://au.domain.com/en/anything/`

**UPDATED**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://au.domain.com/us/^(.*)$ http://au.domain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Only `http://au.domain.com/us/anything` will be redirected to

`http://au.domain.com/en/anything/`

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^au.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^us/(.*)$ http://au.domain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I was hoping to detect the /us/ only on the au.domain.com domain as us.domain.com also has the /us/ in its urls and are not required to be redirected on this domain.